# Why does the mean have $n-1$ degrees of freedom?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, degrees-of-freedom

When calculating the standard deviation of a set of measurements of $X$, you use the formula
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}$$
A common explanation I have found for the  $n-1$ factor is that it refers to the degrees of freedom. As I understand he degrees of freedom is the number of values you can pick, which is equal to the number of samples minus the number of relations between them.

Let's say $n=3$ and we pick values until our vector is fully determined.
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\bar x)\\(4,x_2,x_3,\bar x)\\(4,9,x_3,\bar x)\\(4,9,x_3,7)$$
At this point we have enough information to calculate that $x_3=8$. We could also have picked $x_3$ to calculate $\bar x$. So why isn't the degrees of freedom $n$ since we had to pick $n$ values to fully determine the standard deviation?

Comment: Your example is wrong, you cannot pick a value of the mean $\bar{x}$, as you said number of degrees is equal to sample size minus relations which in this case is $n - 1$

Comment: @Tim that answer is actually pretty helpful but seems to be more about justifying the $n-1$ factor than about degrees of freedom.

Comment: It follows from Cochran's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem

Comment: It isn't the mean that has "degrees of freedom": it's the estimate of the standard deviation.  This issue is covered extensively in [a large number of related posts.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=degrees%20freedom)